# Wpf data grid CurrentCell property fires only once MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a datagrid that looks like:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Applications" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False"  
 AutoGenerateColumns="false" CanUserAddRows="false" ItemsSource="{Binding Applications}" 
 SelectionMode="Single"
 CurrentCell="{Binding CellInfo, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

And I have a question about CurrentCell, it is binded to poeprty in view model that looks like:

```
    private DataGridCellInfo cellInfo;
    public DataGridCellInfo CellInfo
    {
        get => cellInfo;
        set
        {
            cellInfo = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();

            if (cellInfo.Column.DisplayIndex == 1)
            {
                var selectedApplication = (ExtendedApplicationFile)cellInfo.Item;
                ExpandAppDetailsCommand.Execute(selectedApplication);
            }
        }
    }
```

And what it does, it sets correct item and sends it to command that will expend and hide row details window.

Problem is if I click once property is set and it will expand, but when I click second time on same cell, property is not setting and details row is not collapsing. It will work again when I click other cell and get back to it, but that is not I am aiming for.

Comment: That's not how it works. Nothing changes if currentCell is the same... Most like you have to use the Click event or MouseButtonDown event to achieve what you are requiring!

Comment: *"when I click second time on same cell, property is not setting"* - by design. The cell is not changed by such an action. *"that is not I am aiming for"* - you want to toggle some visibility, that's naively either checkbox or togglebutton behavior. If you want to mimic it you have to keep state and handle clicks.

Comment: You can template a control into pretty much anything you like. So you could put a togglebutton in every cell and whatever is currently showing in a cell within that. This seems an unlikely requirement though. Isn't the standard rowdetails behaviour sufficient for your requirement? By default you see the detail template for the selected row. Once you select one you'd need some way to un-select it if you really need that aspect. Like maybe a double click mousegesture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basing on information in comment I came up with simple solution, Ive added cell template with event trigger:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
             <Label Content="{Binding Name}" Width="350">
                   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                         <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
                                  <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.ExpandAppDetailsCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                          </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                 </Label>
           </DataTemplate>                
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Using thin each time I click cell event fires and toggles details view.